# Excel SUMIFs multiple conditions

Tags: sumifs

Am new to Excel functions and would like some help in SUMIFs (am assuming SUMIFs is the right function to use here).

Essentially, I need to match 2 arrays and sum a particular column in case 2 conditions match.

My raw Data looks something like this

```
--- NAV History --------         ---- Premium Paid History ----
A        B           C           G        H          I
Policy   Date        NAV         Policy   Date       Premium Paid
P1       31-Oct-13   280         P1       25-Oct-13  250 
P1       31-Nov-13   310         P2       25-Dec-13  10   
P1       31-Dec-13   550         P1       25-Dec-13  250  
P2       31-Dec-13   13
```

The idea is to compute Total Amount Paid against each policy based on 2 conditions -

1. The policies (A should match G) should match and
2. The NAV date (B) should be less than or equal to premium paid date (H)

I gave it a shot using the formula

```
=SUMIFS(I:I,A:A,"*"&G3:G12&"*")
```

but I am way off from the expected value (E).

```
--- NAV History -------------              ---- Premium Paid History ----
A        B           C     E               G        H          I
Policy   Date        NAV   Expected        Policy   Date       Premium Paid
P1       31-Oct-13   280   250             P1       25-Oct-13  250 
P1       31-Nov-13   310   250             P2       25-Dec-13  10   
P1       31-Dec-13   550   500             P1       25-Dec-13  250  
P2       31-Dec-13   13    10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
=SUMIFS(I:I,G:G,A2,H:H,"<="&B2)
```

No way to test ATM.
Please give it a try.

**Already tested. See SS below:**

[image: sample sheet]

Comment: Thanks. Somehow it came back with 0 as answer. Am trying some combinations using that example to see what works

Comment: you have to check the entries in `Dates` column. It should all be dates. If it is `Text`, then the formula will fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to be working on certain cells for me.I just got to figure out how to set the date consistently on excel (MAC version). It is not behaving as expected.

Comment: np. glad it helped. btw, you can use `ISTEXT` to check if the entry is `TEXT` and then convert if true to date. like this `=IF(ISTEXT(B2),DATEVALUE(B2))`. Assuming your date data for check is in `B2`.

Comment: Thanks. That helps too. Had one more question in the same vein. How do i get the max date condition in there - I want to create a summary table from columns A, B, C which matches the max available date.

Comment: I tried =SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,L2,B:B,"="&MAX(B:B)) but that takes the max of all available dates rather than of each section

Comment: @anhsirk that would be tricky, but i think doable. :) Might as well post another question. We have `Excel Formula` Gods roaming around here. hehe but i'll try it as well and get back as soon as i have answer.