# Excel - Return a third column from between two variables within a bracketed range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnWPt.png)

I've tried to make this as simple as possible; effectively I have two tables, the second one lists pricing strategy for all spirits based on a range of cost prices from entered parameters.

This lists a selection of range of cost prices and allows me to manually read off the retail price, however I'd like to automate it, so that when a cost price in the first table fits in a bracket in the second table it returns that retail price to the first table.

There is a very simplified version attached, I'm looking for the formula that goes in the 'Retail Price Per (ml)' column and returns the result that I have manually entered into the '(Result)' column,

The picture should make it pretty clear.

Comment: how about using "SUMIFS" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371699/excel-sumifs-mutliple-conditions

Comment: I looked at it, but I don't want to add anything together, I want to return a unique result that depends on my data fitting between a range of price brackets. I'm sure at some stage I will be using < or > but I need both and can't figure out how.

Comment: In the given example, if Don Julio 1942 at 2$ per ml fits in the 1.10$ - 2.00$ per ml bracket then I want to return '20.00$'.

Comment: Can you separate the cost intervals in two different columns?

Answer (score 0):

Setting second condition solve it.

`=sumifs(G:G,[first condition target],[first condition],[second condition target],[second condition])`

[image: Like this]

Comment: It certainly does, thank you. What does the ampersand do, I've not used that before in excel.

Comment: ampersand make condition description string. "condition" is string

Comment: "<="&B4 is equivalent "<= 2"